# Closed household sewage system

Tags: plumbing

I was told my sewage system was closed because of a dirty water sump (the sump is sealed). I now have my tubs and sinks gurgling when toilet flushed. How to repair? Thanks

Comment: You need to explain better just what the problem is and what the system consists of. What do you mean when you say your sewage system is closed? Do you have public sewer, a septic system, a sand mound, etc?

Answer (score 2):

If things gurgle when the toilet is flushed, it sounds like it is improperly vented. Or NOT vented or "closed".

To repair it, you need to have venting added in the right places to allow air pressure equalization.

Hire a reputable plumbing contractor if you need it repaired or learn a whole lot about plumbing.

Good Luck!